# Why does tasksel remove so many packages when switching from xubuntu to vanilla gnome?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, gnome, xubuntu

I ran `tasksel`, then deselected `Xubuntu desktop` and selected `Vanilla GNOME` and now observing it is deleting a lot of packages, which look irrelevant, like `samba`, `pulse audio` and etc.

Why?

Comment: Do not use tasksel for removing stuff. It is broken.